# CSS grid for custom theming in Omega?

Tags: theming

I cant find the answer to my question by googeling or in the documentation for the theme but im sure ive heard it exists. Does the Omega theme give you a CSS grid to work with?

So if you wanted to customize a tpl file and have 2 colums, one twice the width of the other, could you just write some CSS a bit like this?

```
<div class="1of3">content here</div>
<div class="2of3">more content here</div>
```

Im happy to use standard classes but Im trying to avoid adding additional CSS, I would have thought the theme (as a grid based layout) would have classes I could use? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, one might argue that's one of the reasons to use Omega in the first place; as per the first two features listed on the project page:

- Fully Responsive Grid layouts based on 960.gs standards.
- 12, 16, 24 Column Layouts built in.

Have a look in the CSS files with names like `alpha-default-normal-12.css` under omega/alpha/css/grid/alpha_default/* to discover what classes are available for you to use.

Those files should make it fairly obvious what conventions Alpha/Omega use for naming those classes too, so you should be able to predict what you need to use easily.

Comment: Im using the fixed width layout but some of the components im using need to have a % width as they get reused in different parts of the site where the container's width varys. It seems I cant use the % CSS grids provided by the theme?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean...if you want to use the CSS grids provided by Omega you can just use them as you would in any normal HTML/CSS project, there's no difference with this being an Alpha/Omega theme. The specific classes you want are in omega/alpha/css/alpha_fluid/normal/*.css

Comment: Ah, might you be asking how you can use classes from the fluid grid system in the fixed width grid system? That's not possible as far as I know, and wouldn't really make sense. A fluid grid is percentage-based, a fixed width is value-based in my experience. If you're mixing the two you're doing something wrong, or at least outside the standard model of a grid system